# Codepush - js and css files (from assets) not loaded in device

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, code-push, react-native-code-push

Currently working on react native app and using codepush to update the app data. I am terribly stuck in a problem where js and css files on webView are not downloading. I checked the 'application support' from home directory. I found that only images are downloaded from codePush but cannot see js or css files.

Provided the folder structure from Xocde and the response getting from CodePush in application support path.

[image]

[image]

Following command used to create main.jsbundle.

```
react-native bundle --platform ios --assets-dest ./ --dev false --entry-file index.ios.js --bundle-output iOS/main.jsbundle
```

To send update to codePush used following command.

```
code-push release-react app_name ios --description "message"
```

I will really appreciate if you can at least point me in a right direction.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to refer more to react-native than to codepush itself, as stated [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/505#issuecomment-219689906) - js and css files will not be bundled and it is not possible to treat them as assets.